# App not installed package appears to be corrupted

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I've an app created using react native. I am trying to install the app on my device.But showing this error "app not installed -package appears to be corrupted".

What would be the reason? I've tried the following method to build apk.

`gradlew assembleRelease`.

Comment: Did you set up signing the app in build.gradle?

Comment: I am generating an unsigned apk actually.

Comment: Then sign it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15743425/1796579

Comment: So do i need generate a signed apk to be installed on a device?

Answer (score 4):

**FOLLOW THESE INSTRUCTIONS ....IT WORKED FOR ME**

**Prerequisite** - You must have a keystore file, If you don't have then Open `cmd` run `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` follow instructions and you are done.You will have a keystore file. Now follow these steps.

1 .On windows `cd android` and then run `gradlew assembleRelease`

2 .Find **APK** at this location `android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk`

3 .Copy this APK to `bin` folder of `jdk` installation directory ( for me directory was `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin` ) [ Basically in this step we are trying to go to the same directory as `jarsigner`]

4 .Also Copy your keystore file to this ( `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin` ) directory.

5 .Now Open `cmd` in `Administrator mode` and run `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin`

6 .Now run `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore 
<<your keystore file name >>  <<your apk file name>> alias_name`

Here goes your **apk** , now find your signed apk here cd `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin` . Run it, Now it should install.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks. But, why didn't it work the facebook way, what is the reason for this extra steps ?

Comment: they have skipped few steps for some reason better know to them

Comment: How about on MacOS?

Answer (score 3):

For me the reason that my phone already had a version of the app installed on it.
Once I remove the app - reinstall the apk it went smoothly.

Answer (score -4):

This will help: - on Latest android studio

Go to Build-> Build Apk(s).

After creating apk you will see a dialog as below.

Click on locate and install it on your phone

Comment: Are you aware this is a react native question ?